# Map aesthetics to LINESTRING geometries with sf in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

The new-ish `sf` package for R makes it really easy to deal with
geographic data in R, and the develompent version of `ggplot2` has a new
`geom_sf()` layer for plotting sf-style geographic data.

Within the `sf` paradigm of working with data, is it possible to map
ggplot aestheics to `LINESTRING` geometries?

For instance, with standard ggplot, it's possible to recreate [Minard's
famous plot of survivors from Napoleon's Grande Armée in
1812](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Joseph_Minard#/media/File:Minard.png)
with ggplot and [this
data](http://www.datavis.ca/gallery/minard/minard.txt), sizing the path
of the army by the number of survivors:

```r
# Install the dev version of ggplot2 for geom_sf()
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")
library(tidyverse)

troops <- read_csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/andrewheiss/69b9dffb7cca392eb7f9bdf56789140f/raw/3e2a48635ae44837955765b5e7747c429b0b5d71/troops.csv")

ggplot(troops) +
  geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, color = direction, 
                group = group, size = survivors),
            lineend = "round")
```

[image]

We can work with this troops data as an `sf` object by creating a new
`geometry` column, like so:

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.6.1, GDAL 2.1.3, proj.4 4.9.3

troops_with_geometry <- troops %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("long", "lat"))

head(troops_with_geometry)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 3 fields
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 24 ymin: 54.5 xmax: 28 ymax: 55
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   survivors direction group          geometry
#>       <int>     <chr> <int>  <simple_feature>
#> 1    340000         A     1 <POINT (24 54.9)>
#> 2    340000         A     1 <POINT (24.5 55)>
#> 3    340000         A     1 <POINT (25.5 ...>
#> 4    320000         A     1 <POINT (26 54.7)>
#> 5    300000         A     1 <POINT (27 54.8)>
#> 6    280000         A     1 <POINT (28 54.9)>
```

If we plot this with `geom_sf`, ggplot will use points:

```r
ggplot(troops_with_geometry) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = direction, group = group))
```

[image]

We can create line strings for each of the groups and directions by
grouping, summarizing, and casting.

```r
troops_lines <- troops_with_geometry %>%
  group_by(direction, group) %>% 
  summarize() %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

head(troops_lines)
#> Simple feature collection with 6 features and 2 fields
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: 24 ymin: 54.1 xmax: 37.7 ymax: 55.8
#> epsg (SRID):    NA
#> proj4string:    NA
#>   direction group                       geometry
#> 1         A     1 LINESTRING (24 54.9, 24.5 5...
#> 2         A     2 LINESTRING (24 55.1, 24.5 5...
#> 3         A     3 LINESTRING (24 55.2, 24.5 5...
#> 4         R     1 LINESTRING (24.1 54.4, 24.2...
#> 5         R     2 LINESTRING (28.3 54.2, 28.5...
#> 6         R     3 LINESTRING (24.1 54.4, 24.2...
```

ggplot can then plot these six connected lines and color them correctly:

```r
ggplot(troops_lines) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = direction, group = group))
```

[image]

However, the survivors data is now gone and there's no way to map size
aesthetics to the new lines.

Is there a way to associate other aestheics (like size) to `sf`-based
`LINESTRING` data? Or, in other words, is there a way to recreate
`ggplot(...) + geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = something))`
using `geom_sf()` and the sf paradigm of working with geographic data?

Comment: `geom_sf` seems to only be available in dev version of ggplot2 (https://github.com/ropensci/seaaroundus/issues/24). I had to install from github (`devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`) before I could replicate.

Comment: Oh yeah, that. You need the dev version :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]You need to create a linestring from each pair of points, within each group. The result is not as pretty because I don't know how to give the lines round endpoints.

```
# within each group repeat each point 
# then slice the first and last out and 
# add a variable called linegroup, which provides grouping for start and endpoints of each line
troops %<>% group_by(group) %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), each = 2)) %>%
  slice(-c(1, n())) %>%
  mutate(linegroup = lapply(1:(n()/2), function(x) rep(x, 2)) %>% unlist) %>% 
  ungroup

# create linestring sf object by summarizing the points, 
# grab the last survivor and direction value of each group (i.e. the 'endpoint' value)
troops_line <- st_as_sf(troops, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  group_by(group, linegroup) %>%
  summarise(survivors = last(survivors), direction = last(direction), do_union = FALSE) %>%
  st_cast("LINESTRING")

gp <- ggplot(troops_line) +
  geom_sf(aes(color = direction, size = survivors), show.legend = "line")
```